# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server

Tags: html, r

I receive the following error when attempting to use the `rvest` package in R:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server

What is causing this error message?  The function is shown below:

```
htmlpage <- read_html("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=42.27925753000045&lon=-71.41616624299962#.V17UH-IrKHs")
```

Comment: Runs fine for me. Could simply be your internet connection.

Comment: having the same problem too. In what kind of computer are you running the code?

Answer (score 10):

I tried different ways and the problem was not in the proxy connection, but in the way that R gets the connection. Through the definition of a binary connection of the url within `url()` the problem was solved.

```
con <- url("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/", "rb") 
lego_movie <- read_html(con)
```

Comment: works for me after trying other methods.. like using httr::GET with proxy etc but those didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a session and then read from it

```
htmlpage <- html_session("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=42.27925753000045&lon=-71.41616624299962#.V17UH-IrKHs", httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.672.2 Safari/534.20"))

htmlpage %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: i originally was getting this error when I was on my HP ZBook work computer while in the office. when i connected my work computer to a hotspot, the issue went away. similarly, when i used my personal HP at home, i did not receive the same error. i am thinking the issue was caused by security settings at my company office.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your work computer is always looking for your company's proxy server, and this happens whether or not you are at work, or using a hotspot, or even at home.

The easiest way to overcome this is to add a parameter `atWork` to your function and then use the `httr::use_proxy()` function to set the appropriate proxy to use:

```
myFunction <- function(arg1, atWork)

    if(atWork){
        proxy.string <- use_proxy("http://proxy-server.YourCompanyName.com", port = 8080)
    } else {
        proxy.string <- use_proxy("")
    }

# then open a session
sess <- html_session(myUrl, proxy.string)

do stuff here
return(result)
}
```

of course, you will need to replace `proxy-server.YourCompanyName` with your actual company's proxy server url.