# “Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached”

Tags: r, web-scraping

When I do some webscraping (using a for loop to scrap multiple pages), sometimes, after scraping the 35th out of 40 pages, I have the following error:

> “Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached”

And sometimes I receive in addition this message:

> “In addition: Warning message: closing unused connection 3”

Below a list of things I would like to clarify:

1) I have read it might need to define explicitly the user agent. I have tried that with:

```
read_html(curl('www.link.com', handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0")))
```

but it did not change anything.

2) I noticed that when I turn on a VPN, and change location, sometimes my scraping works without any error. I would like to understand why?

3) I have also read it might depend of the proxy. How would like to understand how and why?

4) In addition to the error I have, I would like to understand this warning, has it might be a clue that leads to understand the error:

> Warning message: closing unused connection 3

Does that mean that when I am doing webscraping I should somehow at the end call a function to close a connection?

I have already read the following posts on stackoverflow but there is no clear resolution:

[Iterating rvest scrape function gives: "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056103/iterating-rvest-scrape-function-gives-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-time)

[rvest Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached)

[Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794368/error-in-open-connectionx-rb-couldnt-connect-to-server)

Comment: Up......anyone?

Comment: .........................?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463559

```
library(rvest)
url = "http://google.com"
download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")
```